# $u$ is a $C^2$ solution of $u_t - \Delta u = f(u)$ and $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega \times (0,\infty)$. Show if $u(x,0) \geq 0$, then $u(x,t) \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with a smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$ and let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function such that its derivative is bounded, i.e. $|f'| \leq M$. $f(0)=0$. Assume $u$ is a $C^2$ solution of $u_t - \Delta u = f(u)$ in $\Omega \times (0,\infty)$ and $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega \times (0,\infty)$.
Show that if $u(x,0) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \Omega$, then $u(x,t) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \Omega$ and $t>0$.

So far I've tried using energy method, i.e. multiply by $u$ and integrate (then use $|f(u)| \leq K|u|$), which gives me some results of the $L^2$ norm of $u$. I wanted to prove $u_t >0$, but it may not work. What are the other possible directions?

Comment: A maximum principle argument should work nicely here.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Could you be more specific?

Comment: Are you familiar with the maximum principle for the heat equation? You should be able to modify its proof to handle your modification, since at a point where $u$ is trying to decrease past zero we have $f(u)=0$, so it will behave like the heat equation. The gradient bound $|f'| \le M$ should be enough to make the proof go through.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Yes. Thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Sorry, still can't figure it out. Mind giving an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First suppose $v$ is a strict supersolution, i.e. $v_t - \Delta v > f(v)$,
with boundary and initial conditions $v > 0$. If $v$ ever failed to be positive,
by compactness and continuity it must do so *for the first time* at some interior point. At this point we would have:

- $v=0$ by continuity of $v$ (and thus $f(v) = 0$),
- $\Delta v \ge 0$ because $v$ is at a spatial minimum, and
- $\partial_t v \le 0$ because this is the first time $v$ is not positive.

But putting these facts together would give $\partial_t v - \Delta v \le f(v)$, a contradiction. Thus we have shown that strict supersolutions stay positive.

Now, to make this work with $u_t - \Delta u = f(u)$,
we can study the peturbation $$v_{\epsilon}\left(x,t\right)=u\left(x,t\right) + \epsilon e^{2Mt}$$

for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. Since the function we've added is positive, this satisfies $v > 0$ at the initial time and on the boundary; and thanks to the assumption on $f$ we have $$|f(u) - f(v)| \le M|u - v| = \epsilon Me^{2Mt}. \tag{1}$$ Thus

$$\begin{align} \partial_t v - \Delta v &= \partial_t u - \Delta u + 2 \epsilon M e^{2 M t} \\
&= f(u) + 2 \epsilon M e^{2Mt} \\
&\ge f(v) - \epsilon M e^{2Mt} + 2\epsilon M e^{2Mt} > f(v); \tag{by 1}
\end{align}$$
so $v$ is a strict supersolution and thus $v_\epsilon > 0$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. Sending $\epsilon \to 0$, we conclude that $u \ge 0$.

Comment: How to show this one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380914/consider-u-t-delta-u-fu-and-u-0-on-partial-omega-times-0-infty