# Consider $u_t - \Delta u = f(u)$ and $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega \times (0,\infty)$. Show if $u(x,0) \geq 0$, then $u(x,t) \geq 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The question was asked here ([$u$ is a $C^2$ solution of $u_t - \Delta u = f(u)$ and $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega \times (0,\infty)$. Show if $u(x,0) \geq 0$, then $u(x,t) \geq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355755/u-is-a-c2-solution-of-u-t-delta-u-fu-and-u-0-on-partial-omega))

However, my question is if $u(x,0)\leq C$ for all $x \in \Omega$, then how to show that  $u(x,t)\leq Ce^{Mt}$ for all $x \in \Omega$ and $t>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea you can try.  Let $v(x,t)$ solve $\partial_tv-\Delta v=f(v)$ for $v(x,0)=C$, and $w=v-u$.  Then $w$ solves $\partial_tw-\Delta w=f(v)-f(u)$.  By the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
f(v)-f(u)=(v-u)\int_0^1 f'((1-s)u+sv)ds=:w\,F,
$$
where $F(x,t)=\int_0^1f'((1-s)u(x,t)+sv(x,t))ds$.  So $w$ solves 
$$
\partial_tw-\Delta w=wF.
$$
But $wF=0$ when $w=0$, and $w(x,0)\ge 0$, so the supersolution argument you linked to seems to apply.  Note that $v(x,t)\le Ce^{Mt}$, which is straightforward to show, since $v(x,t)=V(t)$ solves $V'(t)=f(V(t))$.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your last sentence? Why is $v(x,t)=V(t)$? Thanks!

Comment: @qiewen There is only one solution to the initial value problem for $v$; since $v(x,t)=V(t)$ is a solution for $V(0)=C$, it must be the unique solution.